# Как вывести данные из плагина Ultimate Member на страницу

Tags: wordpress

Только начал изучение Worpdpress и всякой работы с ним.

Стоит задача - **вывести данные на страницу**, которые хранятся в таблице БД Wordpress'a, которые заполнял пользователь при регистрации.
Для функционала регистрации я использовал плагин Ultimate Member, там я добавил поле "Название компании" с ключем "company_name".

Теперь мне нужно каким-то образом вывести его Название компании на страницу из таблицы БД, подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Если получится выдать ссылки на ресурсы, по изучению того, как работать с БД Wordpress'a, буду безмерно благодарен!

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_user

Comment: Сейчас я пробую вывести данные из таблицы usermeta и думаю конкретно вывести значение surname (вместо company_name решил пока это значение вывести)

Следующим образом я обращаюсь к базе:

`код`
<?php global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta WHERE user_id = 5", OBJECT );
?>`код`

Comment: Отсюда я понял, что нужные данные хранятся в ячейке и смотрю в нее
`код`<?php print_r($results[15])?>`код`

Мне выводится уже вот это вот непонятное для меня

stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => a:10:{s:7:"form_id";s:3:"154";s:10:"um_request";s:0:"";s:8:"_wpnonce";s:7:"surname";s:20:"Имя через регистрацию";} )

Как отсюда мне добиться получения surname? Или я в корне не правильно решаю задачу с выводом данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$user_company_name = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID , 'company_name', true); ?>

<?php echo $user_company_name ?>
```

Честно говоря, я не знаю, насколько правильно именно так выводить данные на страницу, но факт в том, что нужное я вывел.

Comment: Норм. Но правильнее выводить так: `echo $user_company_name`